# when i change the x axis in mathplotlib the graph make no sense

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
src["media"] = media
src["longa"] = longa
src["curta"] =  curta
src["Close"] = close
 
plot.plot(0,label="Media",color="gray")
plot.plot(curta,label="Curta",color="green",linewidth=1)
plot.plot(longa,label="Longa", color="red", linewidth=1)
 
trendColor = (np.where(src['curta'] > (src['longa']),'lime', 'orange'))
src["trendColor"] = trendColor
print(curta)

plot.show()
plot.legend()
```

If I don't add the X axis the graph make sense

[image]

But If i add the close prices of the dataset graph make no sense

[image]

Problem seems so basic I tried to make it new dataframe but doesn't work

Comment: How are you adding the x-axis? Please show the code that results in the two different graphs

Comment: I add the close prices of stock by simply plot.plot(close,longa,label="Longa", color="red", linewidth=1)